# Too big difference in speed of binaries ,produced with different compilers (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, intel

I have used mainly gcc in my last project and today I decided to benchmark different compilers' results.

I used the same source for gcc 4.5,MSVC from Visual Studio 2010 and Intel C++ .The program gets its input from a text file,makes a lot of string manipulations and writes the output to another text file.

I counted only time o

EDIT: benchmarking: 

I counted only time of executing the algorithm ,not of file io. Basically I put 



    `clock_t clock0;
    double z;
    clock0 = clock();`



 in the beginning and 

    `double clock1=(clock() - clock0) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;`





 after the function.

It started with a small file(around 200 lines) and there was almost no difference (around <0.15 sec ).With a 4K lines file MSVC's output worked for 1.23 sec compared to 0.1 for gcc's output.

Finally I tested with 60K lines file :

`(program compiled with ) Intel compiler ran for 6.7 sec and with  gcc : 1 sec.`

Now I just wonder why there is such a difference (that was without optimization flags) and what can be the reason about that.(I used c++0x standard - but obviously Intel compiler supports it).I am not sure if the fact that my code compiles to fast binary only with one compiler isn't alarming

EDIT 2:

I didn't compile it in debug mode with MSVC or Intel

Comment: Did you compile in debug or release mode? Btw, benchmarking without optimization flags is kinda pointless, y'know...

Comment: I don't know why there are so many votes for closing this question and downvotes, too.. Most of the beginner programmers have no clue about compiler options at all (including optimizations, debug symbols, etc) (especially ones, working on VS). Alex may be one of them (apparently). If you have never heard about compiler optimizations and debug/release mode, it's normal to wonder for such things.

Comment: @Kiril: That may be, if @Alex wouldn't have mentioned that everything was done without optimization flags.

Comment: @Xeo - argh, I've missed that, doh! :)

Comment: @Alex: you compiled without optimizations, but not in MSVC's debug mode? So you went into the release mode settings and explicitly disabled all the optimization flags that are normally enabled?

Comment: By the way, I don't really see why this got closed. Is it "subjective and argumentative" to be unaware that benchmarking without optimizations enabled is pointless?

Answer (score 10):

Here we go again...

The STL implementation from Visual Studio does ***really heavy*** iterator checking in debug mode. Then there are the normal debug checks for stack and register integrity. It also does this when no optimizations are turned on afaik. GCC can only be so fast if it does no (or little to no) debug checking whatsoever. Also, taken from my comment:

> benchmarking without optimization flags is kinda pointless

Or you tricked us and compiled in release mode with gcc and in debug mode with Visual Studio / Intel C++...

Answer (score 9):

If you didn't use optimization flags, then the answer can be easily explained by poor debugging facilities in the faster compilers. Micro-benchmarks like this are generally not valid anyway, and it's *definitely* not valid if you don't post the code.

You could likely provide a far bigger speed difference than changing compiler by using algorithmic optimizations, custom memory allocators, and that sort of thing.

Answer (score 7):

Don't measure performance with optimizations disabled.

The reason for not compiling with optimizations is usually for ease of debugging, and so the compiler will generate debug-friendly code when optimizations are disabled. For some compilers (MSVC, for example), that involves adding a lot of runtime checks to help you catch more errors.

If you want to compare performance, do it as if performance *mattered*: by telling the compiler to worry about performance and optimize the code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you compiled the g++, nor what g++ does with regards to
libraries, but `clock()` with VC++ is broken; it measures wall clock
time, and not CPU time, as required by the standard.  It sounds like g++
is picking up a correct version of `clock()`, and Intel is using the one
in the VC++ library.  (When reading a large file, most of the time will
not be CPU time.)

Comment: I don't measure the time of reading or writing to file.However the program needs more than 5 sec to execute even if I measure it with a watch for example.

Comment: @Alex Does it take the same elapsed time (with a watch) for both compilers, running each several times to verify?  If so, it's probably due to some sort of system activity which systematically slows things down.  If not, it's probably because you didn't turn all of the debugging checks off in VC++: even in release mode, some are turned on by default.